# Parsing (Fraction Calculator)

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing

Hi so I need help with parsing in my fraction calculator. I'm completely new to Java and programming and I was wondering if anyone can tell me what's wrong with my code? My goal currently is to create improper fractions from the input given

For example:
1_2/3 + 2_3/4

Should come out of the console like this:
5/3 + 11/4

I really don't know what to do with what I've got right now. It just prints the input. Can someone tell me if I'm going in the right direction?

**MY PROBLEM**
I'm not getting the output I want. The input is being printed out. What do i do?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FracCalc {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Welcome to FracCalc");
            System.out.println("Type expressions with fractions, and I will evaluate them.");

        boolean isTrue = true;
        String in = "";
        while(isTrue) {
            in = input.nextLine();
            if (in.equals("quit")) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for running FracCalc!");
                isTrue = false;
                }else{
                System.out.println("You asked me to compute " + in);
                }
            }
        }
        public static String parse(String in){
            int underscore = in.indexOf("_");
            int slash = in.lastIndexOf("/");

            String wholeStr = in.substring(0, underscore);
            String numeratorStr = in.substring(underscore + 1,slash);
            String denominatorStr = in.substring(slash + 1);
            int whole = Integer.valueOf(wholeStr);
            int numerator = Integer.valueOf(numeratorStr);
            int denominator = Integer.valueOf(denominatorStr);
            int newNumerator = whole * denominator + numerator;
            String newS = newNumerator + " / " + denominator;

            if (underscore<0 & slash<0) {
                return wholeStr;
            } else if (underscore<0 & slash>0) {
                return numeratorStr + " / " + denominatorStr;
            } else if (underscore>0 & slash>0) {
                in = newS;
            } else if (underscore>0 & slash<0) {
                return "Error";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a real question, tell us what's wrong with *your* current code (besides compilation error for parse and parse never being used)

Comment: I really don't know. Why does the parse need a return when I already have returns?

Comment: because some path aren't handled (like underscore and slash = 0)

Comment: so should i change the whole if else statement?